# How do i increase speed of my site by reduce time to fetch dns of my website?

Tags: domains, htaccess, dns, performance, magento

My website "happyclothing.in" took 5 seconds to load. where it took 2 seconds to fetch the dns . How do i reduce it to 0 second.[image: here the pingdom result]

Answer (score 2):

It did not take two seconds to lookup the DNS in the image to posted, seems like it took about 0.65. Getting it to zero is not possible, the only way for the DNS lookup to be zero is if the client has cached it already.

If you want to increase the performance of your DNS you should look at purchasing a DNS solution from a provider with Anycast. I'm using [DNSMadeEasy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/) and is very happy with them. I'm sure there are other good suppliers as well.

You might get a tiny performance gain by having a long TTL, like 24 hours, but not much. And if you are using a fast DNS provider it's going to be even less of a gain.

**Update:**
I realized that what took two seconds was probably the DNS lookup times combined, and not just the first one...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your hosting not the DNS. Since your using Pingdom (which may I add is a biased checker) you should look at the bottom of the legends, YELLOW = `The web browser is waiting for data from the server` this in the industry is known as server first byte. Often a high response time on the first byte means the hosting isn't responding as quickly as it should and most likely because its cheap hosting with a high contention ratio. Server first byte is often the main factor when comparing cheap hosting to expensive hosting.

If your serious about testing your server then you need to test the your hosting with simultaneous connections in the targeted region. If you expect to have 20 visitors online at any one time then that's how many simultaneously  speed tests you should run. Using a singular test with only 1 pass is not only pointless its biased too. Do a test with multiple passes and as many simultaneous tests as you need.

A good example of a good 'first byte' of my [own site is here](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/EFJi3/https://www.bybe.net) but again this is one test... it shouldn't be considered accurate because of the singular test and routing changes from ISP to ISP. You need to do a lot of testing for accurate results.